# VSTS NuGet step restore error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I get an error during execute NuGet restore step in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). I didn’t set nothing special but the error appears. The error is:

> 2016-04-10T16:53:36.3476846Z ##[debug]Adding credentials section to NuGet.config
>   2016-04-10T16:53:36.5691737Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>       2016-04-10T16:53:36.5701787Z ##[error]   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
>       2016-04-10T16:53:36.5711737Z ##[error]   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
>       2016-04-10T16:53:36.5721738Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>       2016-04-10T16:53:36.5721738Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Here all the details. At the beginning of few screen shots:

[Configuration Bild Step in VSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g4Ty.png)
[Logs from output console in VSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei62P.png)

My main nuget configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<repositories>
  <repository path="..\Aleksandra.Tests\packages.config" />
  <repository path="..\Aleksandra\packages.config" />
</repositories>
```

Next subconfigs look like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

… and ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore#!**/) article about the package restore. To quote the important points, `repositores.config` file will be automatically regenerated when needed. Same applies in general to the `packages` folder. You can safely remove them from source control.

Also, you can leave the *Path to NuGet.config* textbox blank. Unless you have special needs (e.g. private feeds for which you'd need authentication), you don't need that file, all `packages.config` files will be picked up in the solution.

Comment: God, so much time I spent to resolve the problem. Removing of Repositories.config was enough to resolve this. So a simple solution that even improbable. Thanks a lot.